# Why I can't have declaration and logical operator together?

Tags: c++

For efficiency reason (though very small) I would like to declare and assign a variable within the if condition block.

I.e. instead of saying

```
if(a != 0 && a->b >= 10){
    int c = a->b
    ...
}
```

I want to assign int c at the first place and say

```
if(a != 0 && (int c = a->b) >= 10){
    ...
}
```

In its most straightforward way (to me) of doing that, I get compile error. does anyone know if it is/isn't possible to do this in c++?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth.

Comment: I'm confused.. You access b with `a->` and `a.` which one?

Comment: You can't do assignations where the C++ compiler expects a boolean statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(a != 0) {
    int c = a->b;

    if (c >= 10) {
        //using c here
    }

    // common cleanup here
}
```

Comment: cool GSerg, that is exactly the process I passed and wanted to skip nested IF cases coz I would have needed to repeat one piece of code for both resulting ELSE situations and that is not beautiful.

Comment: @nino Could you not instead move this piece of code outside the inner `if` so that it's always executed in the outer `if`?

Comment: I don't think so, because if inner IF holds, that piece of code shall not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think this would optimize anything?

Even assuming that you are allowed to declare and initialize a variable inside a condition (which is not possible in C++ since the compiler wants something that can be evaluated and a declaration doesn't return anything) this will be done every time the condition is evaluated (unless you shortcircuit it, which is the case in your snippet) but nothing would change anyway: you are still declaring and initializing a variable, no matter where.

Comment: The point of the question is that when the condition is true, `a->b` is immediately evaluated again. If `a->b` is an expensive operation, it might make sense to only evaluate it once.

Comment: I still don't see any point in optimization: assigning `a->b` to a temporary before the `if` and then using it in case is as costly as the optimization that he would like to be allowed to use.

Comment: @GSerg: ok, in such a case you would have two nested `if`s, with `int c=a->b` immediately inside the first one.

Comment: One nit: a declaration doesn't return anything, but this is perfectly valid: `if (int x = foo()) { /* do something with x */ }`. Personally, I don't like OP's syntax, but I don't see why one should be valid and the other not.

Comment: thanks moswald, right, it doesn't work when you add boolean evaluations to the statement. i.e. this won't work if you say if((int x = foo()) > 10)

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you have it in the first condition. However, the comparison precedes the assignment in this case and you'll not get what you want

```
int a = 3;
int x = 0;
if ( bool b = a > 5 && x < 2) {
printf("%d",b);
}
```

Comment: well, the order matters to me coz I'm first checking if the object exists in order to call a function on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = (a == 0 ? 0 : a->b);
if(a != 0 && c >= 10){

    ...
}
```

If you want to avoid using `a->b` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Patrik for suggestion, this idea works but has the drawback of defining the variable c in a bigger scope than required.